# Detect CreateProcess or who created the process

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I detect the name of the application that created my application's process?

For example, if someone wanted, they could call CreateProcess and pass it the suspended flag and inject into my application.

Is there a way to block CreateProcess or to figure out what process created an instance of my application?

I've hooked loadlibrary, createthread and all the other easy stuff but CreateProcess seems like it can bypass that.

I'm doing it for fun and learning, not for real world use. I just haven't seen anything that detects CreateProcess..

Any ideas at all?

Comment: CreateProcess is wrapper for NtCreateProcess with some checking.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/28/10503865.aspx

Comment: How would you expect this to work? Assume someone injects code to your application and overwrites arbitrary API functions. Further assume there is a magic `WhoLaunchedProcess` function. Why wouldn't someone replace this function to return "Windows Explorer"?

Comment: I don't know.. I just wanted to know if there was a way or not.. I did say it wasn't for real-world/practical use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the parent process ID using the tool help library:

- Call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`.
- Call `Process32First` and `Process32Next` to enumerate the processes.
- At some point you will encounter a [`PROCESSENTRY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx) struct for which `th32ProcessID` is the process ID of your process.
- Read out the `th32ParentProcessID` member to find the process ID of your parent.
- Now that you know the parent process, you can enumerate again to gain information about it.

Be prepared for the parent process to have been terminated before you reach this point.

Comment: Of course, the caller may have patched those functions to return false information.